# How to "reverse" rsync -L?

Tags: zsh, rsync

From the docs for `rsync`'s `-L` flag:

> -L, --copy-links    transform symlink into referent file/dir

This question is about how to "reverse" a transfer that was originally done using `rsync -L ...`.

---

It's easiest for me to explain what I mean here by "reverse" with a simple concrete example.

**The setup**

Suppose I have directories `/tmp/SOURCE/` and `/tmp/TARGET/`, as shown below:

```
$ /usr/bin/tree -aF /tmp/SOURCE/ /tmp/TARGET/
/tmp/SOURCE/
├── A.d/
│   ├── w
│   └── x
├── B.d/
│   └── z
├── C.d/
│   ├── w -> ../A.d/w
│   └── y -> ../A.d/x
└── D.l -> B.d/
/tmp/TARGET/
```

In particular, note the following details:

- the contents of `/tmp/SOURCE/C.d` are relative symlinks pointing to regular files in `/tmp/SOURCE/A.d`;

  - the basenames of symlink `/tmp/SOURCE/C.d/w` and of its referent are the same;
  - the basenames of symlink `/tmp/SOURCE/C.d/y` (namely `y`) and of its referent (namely, `x`) are different;
- `/tmp/SOURCE/D.l` is a relative symbolic link to `/tmp/SOURCE/B.d`;
- `/tmp/TARGET/` is currently empty.

From this initial state, I run the sort of commmand mentioned in this post's title, *the sort of command I want to "reverse"* (as explained further below):

```
$ rsync -L -a /tmp/SOURCE/C.d /tmp/SOURCE/D.l /tmp/TARGET
```

After I run this command, `/tmp/TARGET/` looks like this:

```
$ /usr/bin/tree -aF /tmp/TARGET/
/tmp/TARGET/
├── C.d/
│   ├── w
│   └── y
└── D.l/
    └── z
```

Note in particular that, although under both `/tmp/SOURCE` and `/tmp/TARGET` the relative paths

```
C.d/w
C.d/y
D.l/z
```

exist, only those under `/tmp/TARGET` are "real" paths.  By a "real path" `$P` I mean that, roughly speaking, the output of `readlink -f $P` is again `$P` (or, more precisely,`${P:a}`).  E.g.

```
$ readlink -f /tmp/TARGET/C.d/w
/tmp/TARGET/C.d/w
```

but

```
$ readlink -f /tmp/SOURCE/C.d/w
/tmp/SOURCE/A.d/w
```

---

**The problem**

In the current context, what I mean by "reversing" the previous `rsync -L` command is basically to copy the regular files under `/tmp/TARGET/` onto their *originals* under `/tmp/SOURCE`, leaving the *structure* of `/tmp/SOURCE` unchanged.

In particular, after this "reverse transfer", the symlinks under `/tmp/SOURCE` should remain symlinks, and should point to *exactly* the same referents as they did to before.

I'm looking for a way to carry out such "reversal" that is comparable in complexity/difficulty to the `rsync -aL` command used to perform the "forward" transfer in the first place.

---

One shortcoming of this simple example is that it is *so simple* that one is tempted to solve the problem with brute force.  E.g.

```
$ rsync /tmp/TARGET/C.d/w /tmp/SOURCE/A.d
$ rsync /tmp/TARGET/C.d/y /tmp/SOURCE/A.d/x
$ rsync /tmp/TARGET/D.l/z /tmp/SOURCE/B.d
```

IOW, in such a simple situation, this brute force approach is not very much more difficult than it was to run the original `rsync -L` transfer.  In general, however, the brute force strategy can be vastly more difficult to carry out, when compared to the original transfer.

This example is oversimplified also because the source and target hosts are the same.  *In general, they won't be,* so please avoid solutions that rely on this feature of the example.

---

FWIW, the following script creates the set-up of the toy example above.

```
BASEDIR=/tmp/test1

# uncomment the following line before running this script a second time
# rm -rf $BASEDIR/SOURCE $BASEDIR/TARGET

mkdir -p $BASEDIR/SOURCE/{A,B,C}.d $BASEDIR/TARGET
touch $BASEDIR/SOURCE/{A.d/{w,x},B.d/z}
ln -s ../A.d/w $BASEDIR/SOURCE/C.d/w
ln -s ../A.d/x $BASEDIR/SOURCE/C.d/y
ln -s B.d $BASEDIR/SOURCE/D.l
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are options to allow rsync to not disturb symbolic links on the remote when they refer to directories, but it doesn't seem to have an option to not replace symbolic links to files by real files.

So what you might do is initially preserve the symbolic links to files in SOURCE in some way, eg by renaming them or listing them into a file, then do the rsync preserving directory symbolic links, then restore the file symbolic links, copying the data from the real file to the restored symbolic link and then removing the real file. Here's a potential script:

```
find /tmp/SOURCE -type l ! -xtype d -exec mv {} {}.lnk \;
cd /tmp/TARGET || exit
rsync -a -R --no-implied-dirs --keep-dirlinks . /tmp/SOURCE/
find /tmp/SOURCE -type l ! -xtype d |
while read fname
do base=${fname%.lnk}
   cp "$base" "$fname" 
   mv "$fname" "$base"
done
```

I leave you to cope with weird filenames properly. 
I'm not sure that the `-R --no-implied-dirs` is necessary, but I'll let you experiment with that.

Comment: Thanks, that worked nicely.  In my informal tests, I found that the `-R --no-implied-dirs` was not necessary.  Also unnecessary is the `cd` to `/tmp/TARGET`.  Instead, I just replaced the `.` argument in the `rsync` command with `/tmp/TARGET/`.  This is better anyway, since, in general, the (original) target directory may be on a remote host.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this directly within `rsync`. The `--keep-dirlinks` (`-K`) option will keep symlinked directories untouched, but symlinked files will still be overwritten.

The closest solution I can find for this, is a little (`bash`) script

```
( cd TARGET && find . -type f -print0 | sed 's!^./!!' ) |
    while IFS= read -d $'\0' -r f
    do
        s=$(readlink -f SOURCE/"$f")
        rsync -a TARGET/"$f" "${s:-f}"
    done
```

This takes each file in `TARGET` one at a time, checks for a symlink target in `SOURCE` and applies `rsync` to that directly.